# printf performance in a HTTP Server with LibEvent

Tags: c, libevent

I've tried a small implementation of HTTP Server with LibEvent & Hiredis [here](https://gist.github.com/dspezia/2273908)

Normally the code gives a good 25k req/sec, but if I have a simple printf ; for ex in

`get_cb (somewhere in L29)`

```
printf("some dummy content\n");
```

this affects the performance by almost 3-4 times ..

Is there a specific way of inserting log statements, while using Libevent ?

Comment: That's because `printf` outputs to the screen. And this is relatively slow operation which takes some time (especially with flusing).

Comment: run your program with stdout redirected to a file, e.g. `./myserver >stdout.log` This should be quite faster than printing to your terminal

Comment: Does the server run on embedded device or a full-fledged PC ? In the former case, you can ouput debug statement through the RS232 port (it takes also its toll on perfs, but less than printf). On the latter, use the mail service (e.g root@localhost) or (/var/log/) and a SSH connection.

Comment: @nos that was useful. i will try the other part now, opening a file at the start, and appending to it. will see the performance of that and let you know .. :)

Comment: @maverik yes, i understood that, but wanted to see a way still, to have the printf (or in other words, a log stmt)

Comment: @georgesl this runs on a PC

Comment: @user1460887, use specialized logging library, syslog or redirection (as nos said)